# Google Docs Spreadsheet to an array Google Maps

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-docs

I have a webpage on a WordPress site that places markers on a map based on information stored in a google doc spreadsheet. This allows a few select editors to insert closure (map markers with infowindows) information on a google doc spreadsheet and the page will map it on a google map. I am so close to getting it work, but i cant seem to get the google doc to spit out the information in the form I need.

Here is the code I have to extract info out of Google Docs:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];

    var itm = entry["gsx$item"].$t;
    var lng = parseFloat(entry["gsx$longitude"].$t);
    var lat = parseFloat(entry["gsx$latitude"].$t);
    var info = entry["gsx$information"].$t;
    var status = entry["gsx$status"].$t;

    if (lat != "0" && lng != "0") {
    var closures = [itm, lng, lat, info];
    //closures1.push("[" + itm + "," + lat + "," + lng + "," + info + "]");
    //alert(closures1);
    }


}
```

You can see the section at the bottom is what I am struggling with. I need the information in the spreadsheet out put in an array form, but with multiple arrays each. I need the information above to come out looking like the array below.

```
var closures = [    ['1', 32.980000, -97.250369, 'Single left lane closed on southbound William D. Tate Avenue from south of Mustang Drive to Stone Myers Pkwy. to move barrier wall. One right lane will remain open.'], ['2', 32.933500, -97.058800, 'Two right lanes closed on southbound SH 121 south of the Hall Johnson off-ramp to move barrier wall. One left lane will remain open.'], ];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if your json feed entry works, your add should look something like this..

```
var closures = [];    //first create an empty array

for (var i = 0....
    var entry = "json.fee....
    ....
    ....
    if (lat != "0" && lng != "0") {
        var closure = [itm, lng, lat, info];  //then you create a local array to store the values 
        closures[closures.length] = closure;  //then you add this local array as one element of the global array.
    }
}
```

Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/oukcyz0x/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GeoSheets](http://www.geosheets.com).  It's a free add-on for Google Spreadsheets that makes it easy to make a map directly from your spreadsheet.  Creating the map should be as simple as putting the locations in one column and the details about the closure in a labeled column as described in the [docs](https://geosheets.com/docs/advanced).

```
=GEO_MAP(A1:B3, "closures")
```

That function will return a link to your map.  From there, you can get the embed code to put on your site.  The map will sync in realtime as new closures are added to your spreadsheet.  Here's an example using the data you gave:

https://www.geosheets.com/map/s:3ybe7eAR/closures